Google Nest Outdoor Camera - Re-Wiring (Wire Type)
Last year, I had an ADT system installed, along with some Google outdoor cameras. I have an extra camera that I acquired recently and would like to follow a similar setup as the other cameras.
From what I've see thus far, it looks like ADT used the power supply from the original camera, cut the usb part off, spliced it with some additional wiring into an AC plug. It would seem like low voltage wire for these cameras but I would like more technical details on the items used so I can head to my Lowes or HomeDepot for some items.
Wire splice/connection and the receptacle plug shown below.
Question is, what type of wiring do I need? Would this available at Lowes or HomeDepot? I found the switching adaptor on eBay but unsure of wiring details.





What exactly is your question?

Updated question, looking for what type of wiring I need.

That's an AC-DC adapter.  The USB connector before was likely simply a power adapter from a USB wall plug, which basically converts AC to the 5V DC used by USB devices.  If you're gonna use the same type of AC-DC adapter, 18 gauge wire would be fine.  If you're gonna run it inside a wall or something, use Class 2 wire (if surface only, no need).

Gauge wire was term I was looking for, thank you for suggestion the wire gauge.

I would assume Lowes or HomeDepot would carry the wire?

@Muhnamana -- you may have to look around a bit to find 18/2 cable that's outdoor rated

It's also not clear what the wire connections are like on the camera end.

@Huesmann The tech used the original power cord that plugs into the back of the camera. I assume since there is splice, they cut off the USB part and ran the new wire into the adapter.

@ThreePhaseEel Is the wire essentially speaker wire? I found some 18/2 outdoor rated labeled as speaker wire.

Do you need to run it through a wall?

@Muhnamana is your outdoor rated speaker wire marked CL2?

Yes, I will need to mount to the side of the house. Stucco exterior. Run wire through wall and power adaptor preferably.

@ThreePhaseEel Yes, CL2 rated. I found a product on Amazon. https://www.amazon.com/Askcable-Electrical-Conductor-Speaker-Extension/dp/B0C65JSPL1?source=ps-sl-shoppingads-lpcontext&ref_=fplfs&smid=A458UVQHMHJAI&th=1

@Muhnamana -- CL2 rated outdoor wire is fine for what you're doing then
